# set country by default using

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to set my the country dropdown to usa soon as the page loads by default without hard coding.

```
            <tr>
                <td><label for="State_Province__c">State/Province:</label></td>
                <td><select id="State_Province__c" name="State_Province__c" title="State/Province"></select></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="Country__c">*Country:</label></td>
                <td><select id="Country__c" name="Country__c" title="Country"></select></td>
            </tr>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                populateCountries("Country__c", "State_Province__c");
                jQuery("#Country__c").val("USA").change();
                });
        </script>
```

Comment: Add please `populateCountries()` definition and HTML code.

Comment: Likely `populateCountries()` is calling an AJAX method, which is asynchronous, and hasn't completed by the time `.val("USA")` is called.

Comment: As @Draco18s mentioned if you are appending options via the `populateCountries` call then you will need to use the AJAX call back to set the select's selected value, but this is a guess until we can see that function.